# Understanding AurioTouch

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio

In the AurioTouch example for iPhone the following code is used to add samples into a draw buffer that gets used when rendering to the screen

```
SInt8 *data_ptr = (SInt8 *)(ioData->mBuffers[0].mData);
for (int i=0; i<numFrames; i++)
{
    if ((i+drawBufferIdx) >= drawBufferLen)
    {
        cycleOscilloscopeLines();
        drawBufferIdx = -i;
    }

    drawBuffers[0][i + drawBufferIdx] = data_ptr[2];
    data_ptr += 4;
}
```

I simply cannot understand why this works. The actual mData buffer contains *SInt32* samples in fixed point 8.24 LPCM.

However, the loop seems to be extrating the 3rd byte of every sample as an SInt8 and using this value (which will range from -128 to +127) to represent the sample.

How is this a valid value for the sample if the sample is meant to be a 24 bit value? Why is it looking at the 3rd byte of an SInt32 and casting to an SInt8?

I am very confused. Kudos to anyone who can explain it to me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The top 8 bits of a 24-bit number are the most significant part.  The remaining less significant part is too small, relative to full-scale, to display on an iPhone display.  The most significant 8-bits are located in the 3rd byte of a little-endian 24 bit data type in memory.

Comment: Thankyou. I have elaborated on this answer here: http://www.kevatron.co.uk/understanding-auriotouch